# Does setTimeout function runs in background or in parallel?

Tags: javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("hello async")
     }, 1000);
console.log("Hello sync");
```

setTimeout function console the hello async after delays of 1sec, after consoling Hello sync, so does it runs in background or in parallel.

Comment: javascript is always single threaded. So, neither. it runs in the main thread approximately 1 second later.

Comment: (exception is "worker" threads, but those launch a whole new instance of the VM, so no memory is shared between these types of threads)

Comment: @Garr Godfrey so setTimeout function runs in the main thread after 1 sec later?

Comment: What do you consider the difference between "in background" and "parallel"?

Comment: @KunalRanjan: `setTimeout` *itself* runs immediately, scheduling some operation to happen after some amount of time.  *That operation* will then run after approximately that amount of time.  It's not really clear what you're actually trying to ask.  Have you encountered some issue that you think this is related to?

Comment: you said it runs immeditely, that means it runs in the main thread?

Comment: @KunalRanjan: There's only one thread (in any given instance of a JavaScript engine).  So, yes, it runs in the main thread.  The only thread.  Where everything in JavaScript runs.

Comment: @David That's not the whole story. Client-side JavaScript is executed by the JavaScript runtime that is built into the client. That client is a multi-threaded piece of software and the client can and does run multiple tasks in multiple threads. It's just that the client provides a single thread for the JavaScript runtime, so JavaScript execution happens in that single thread.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Fair enough, there's definitely "more to it" in any given context.  But the code shown isn't taking advantage of worker threads or anything of that nature.  And while the host environment (likely a browser in this case) can implement its timer any way it sees fit, I don't think the OP is really getting to that level.  I'm not sure *what* the OP is genuinely trying to understand here.  `setTimeout` just schedules something to happen later.  I suspect they're drastically overthinking it as an academic curiosity, or we are elbow deep in the Y of an XY Problem.

Comment: @David Yes, but I think that the important point that a lot of people skip over is that `setTimeout()` itself is asynchronous. The counting and scheduling you talk about happens in a different thread than the JS runtime.

Comment: @all , hitting vote down button on this question indicates that the lot of developers in community having very less understanding of javascript as they are unable to visualise the process map , their understanding is textual based on textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, `setTimeout()` is actually [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) and `window` is not part of the Document Object Model or a native object in JavaScript.

When you call `setTimeout()`, you are accessing a Web API and what happens next is that the **browser** will (asynchronously) begin a timer and when the time has elapsed, the callback function will be placed into the event queue. The next time the JavaScript runtime is idle, it will check the event queue and execute the next item in that queue.

So, while the callback function is executed by the JavaScript runtime (and thus the single thread of that runtime), the timer itself is handled in a separate thread of the browser.

Comment: the callback function should run in stack(function execution context) when it is empty?

Comment: @KunalRanjan Yes, that's what I mean when I say *"The next time the JavaScript runtime is idle, it will check the event queue and execute the next item in that queue."*

Answer (score 2):

You can block the main thread and see that it runs in the same thread

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello async")
}, 1000);
const old = Date.now()
// block thread fo 1.5s
while (Date.now() < old + 1500) {}
console.log("Hello sync");
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout effectively adds the function (and frame) to a queue to be run later when the main thread is not busy.

Of course, it isn't really a queue, as they are prioritized and ordered.

Using `console.log` can further complicate things, because that is run the same way. What you output using `console.log` isn't converted to a string and output until the main thread is not busy (behavior may vary on node.js or where `console` object is not the default).

Comment: *Of course, it isn't really a queue, as they are prioritized and ordered.* <-- That's  exactly what a queue is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Typically a queue is defined as FIFO, but there are variations of a pure queue that can have a different order.